# AMP Pages Multiple Analytics Solutions Implementation (Google Analytics and Adobe Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, adobe-analytics, accelerated-mobile-page

Is it possible to have Multiple Analytics Solutions such as Google Analytics and Adobe Analytics implemented on the Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP Pages)?

[Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyDn7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Via the official AMP.dev page:](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-measure/configure-analytics/analytics_basics?referrer=ampproject.org)

> "You can use both amp-pixel and amp-analytics in your pages: amp-pixel
>   for simple page view tracking, and amp-analytics for everything else.
>   You can also add multiples of each tag. If you're working with
>   multiple analytics providers, you will need one tag per solution. Keep
>   in mind that simpler AMP pages are better for users, so if you don’t
>   need the extra tags, don’t use them."

So, YES, you can use multiple tracking tools, you will just need to add multiple tags for each tool.